# Gulp watch only fires once with watchify

Tags: gulp, watchify

I have run into a problem with some weird interplay between watchify and gulp.watch. When we use watchify with polling, which I need to do because it runs in a vagrant environment, then the gulp.watch task only fires the first time the files are changed.

gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var util = require('gulp-util');
var eslint = require('gulp-eslint');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var watchify = require('watchify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

function bundle(bundler) {
    return bundler
    .bundle()
    .on('error', (error) => util.log(util.colors.red('Error compiling scripts:'), error.message))
    .pipe(source('./app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
}

gulp.task('default', ['build', 'watch']);

gulp.task('build', ['lint', 'scripts']);

gulp.task('lint', function() {
    gulp.src('./src/**/*.js')
    .pipe(eslint());
});

gulp.task('scripts', ['lint'], function() {
    var bundler = browserify({
        entries: ['./src/app.js'],
        cache: {},
        packageCache: {},
        fullPaths: true,
    });

    var watcher = watchify(bundler, {poll: true});
    watcher.on( 'update', () => {
        util.log( 'Now Updating Scripts...');
        return bundle(watcher);
    });

    return bundle(watcher);
})

gulp.task('watch', ['build'], function() {
    gulp.watch(['./src/**/*.js'], ['lint']);
})
```

Sample repository here: https://github.com/mudetroit/watchify-gulp-watch-issue

When you run gulp and change the file twice after the initial compile you see the following.

```
[12:02:49] Using gulpfile ~/repo/watchify-gulp-watch-issue/gulpfile.js
[12:02:49] Starting 'lint'...
[12:02:49] Finished 'lint' after 24 ms
[12:02:49] Starting 'scripts'...
[12:02:49] Finished 'scripts' after 98 ms
[12:02:49] Starting 'build'...
[12:02:49] Finished 'build' after 6.17 μs
[12:02:49] Starting 'watch'...
[12:02:49] Finished 'watch' after 8.41 ms
[12:02:49] Starting 'default'...
[12:02:49] Finished 'default' after 11 μs
[12:03:48] Starting 'lint'...
[12:03:48] Finished 'lint' after 3.87 ms
[12:03:48] Now Updating Scripts...
[12:03:55] Now Updating Scripts...
```

A couple of items worth noting, if I don't use watchify and do full recompiles it works just fine, but this is to slow to be useful in practice. If I take the poll off it works fine, but this stops it from working in the vagrant environment with NFS. Been trying to understand what is going on here all morning and not getting anywhere so hoping I can get some help.

Answer (score 1):

So after doing a bunch of digging we found [the culprit](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/issues/345). It seems since both gulp and watchify use chokidar under the hood. An attempted optimization by chokidar causes the problem. Worked around it for now by launching separate processes.

Comment: Hi Matt great to see someone having the same issue... thanks for digging! How can you run this is in separate processes? Do you have a example?